# python-requests: is it possible to bypass HTTPS for speed

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, profiling

Is it possible to bypass the HTTPS on python3+requests to gain speed?

Profiling says SSL handling is the slowest part of my script:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      133    0.377    0.003    0.377    0.003 {method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects} <--- slowest part 380ms/web access
      232    0.131    0.001    0.131    0.001 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x000000007419C430}
      153    0.087    0.001    0.090    0.001 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:830(get_data)
        1    0.023    0.023    0.023    0.023 {method 'do_handshake' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}


import requests    
resp = requests.get("https://uk.finance.yahoo.com", verify=False)
```

verify=False just disables the certificate checking, but SSL/TLS still happens in the background.

I didn't find any option to use the dumbest cipher (eg. 0bit) type to gain speed.

Security is not my goal in this script.
I already upgraded my packages with pip. Environment Win10 x64.
As I tested most http:// addresses only allow/redirect to https://

Comment: did you check out requests session? It uses the same connection to send multiple requests, it might not verify again and again, though not sure...

Comment: If the web API doesn't expose access over http (or another protocol), you'll be forced to utilize https which will require encryption/decryption between the server and the client. The server has no way of knowing that you want to forgo encryption. As well, there will be some kind of performance penalty inherent with this, as that is the point of encyrption, to be hard to quickly solve based on complexity such that an attacker has a hard time breaking the encryption cipher.

Comment: Apart from what has already been said, you might consider checking the `context` argument of [urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen).

Comment: "Security is not my goal in this script." Why do you use HTTPS then? Switch back to HTTP. HTTPS with verify=False is basically useless in the sense that it gives you the same level of security as HTTP at the end of the day...  But HTTP becomes more and more deprecated, browsers show it as insecure, etc. so the world is moving to HTTPS and proper HTTPS needs real encryption (not 0bit cipher) and certificates verification. I am not sure you are really focusing on the part of the problem that you should focus on. (I guess you are attempting something like realtime quotes by scraping a website...)

Comment: I have just tested session with sess.verify=False, it didn't make any difference for one/first web call.
Unfortunately everyone forces HTTP to HTTPS nowadays.
Maybe protocol downgrade would be possible, but many sites dropped support for old/0bit ciphers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bypass the use of HTTPS if the URL you use says `https://`. The very meaning of `https://` is that HTTPS gets used. You might try to use `http://` instead of `https://`. But this will only work if the server actually exposes the resource in question with a simple `http://`. Typically today an access to `http://...` will just redirect to `https://...` and you end up at the same URL as you had before, only even slower due to the overhead of the additional HTTP request.